# What is the difference between Lie group sim3 and 3d affine transformation?

Tags: lie-groups, rigid-transformation, robotics

I am confused between 3D rigid affine (with scale, without shear) transformation and Lie group's sim(3) matrix.

3D affine should be $[sR|t; 0 1]$
\begin{matrix}
s\cdot r_{11} & s\cdot r_{12} & s\cdot r_{13} & t_1\\
s\cdot r_{21} & s\cdot r_{22} & s\cdot r_{23} & t_2\\
s\cdot r_{31} & s\cdot r_{32} & s\cdot r_{33} & t_3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}

we rotate, scale and then translate a 3D point using 3D affine transform. Here the translation is done after rotate and scale.

sim3, according to [1], the definition is $[{R} \vert t; 0 1/s]$

\begin{matrix}
r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} & t_1\\
r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23} & t_2\\
r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33} & t_3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & s^{-1}
\end{matrix}

I have a two sets of 3D points. I used a c++ library to estimate the rigid transformation (with scale) between the points. How do I know if the answer is a 3D affine matrix or a sim3 matrix?

Can we have different matrices for a sim3 and affine transform that takes us from 3D points set-1 to set-2?

Is sim3, a way of representing the sequence rotate-translate-scale ?

Reference:
[1] http://ethaneade.com/lie_groups.pdf

Answer (score 2):

maybe [this paper](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/interp-SIM.pdf) very be helpful. (I am not able to add as a comment, sorry)